# how to convert html file to word file in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html file to convert into MS Word. My PHP code is below:

```
include("connection.php");
extract($_REQUEST);
ob_start();
include("counties/$county_name/$file");
$html_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;Filename=3_day_notice_fad_word/$html_content");
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API. Please go through it.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

**You can see in above link's page, they have converted something like below:**

```
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...But what if I convert html files in pdf??

Comment: Although you asked for word in original SO: there are also libraries/APIs that convert HTML to PDF... Google will let you find FPDF, MPDF, TCPDF, DOMPDF.